# Get rid of the animation completion delay

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, delay

Every time when I use the completion of an animation, there is some kind of delay.
How can I make sure the delay will not be there anymore?

This is a part of my code:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^ {
  [presentingViewController presentViewController:load animated:YES completion:nil];
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not dismiss animated if you don't wish to animate.  If you animate, completion will fire when animation is complete, hence the delay.